# Why does my LM311 comparator's output seem to be inverted?

Tags: integrated-circuit, comparator

From what I understand, the potential difference between its output pin (COL OUT) and GND is equal to the voltage of source when the potential of IN+ (pin 2) is greater than IN- (pin3). The opposite seems to be happening with my circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LM311's output is "open-collector" meaning that the output is internally tied to the collector of a transistor. The LM311 will turn on and off the transistor which will connect the output to GND or make the output high impedance. It will not source current or make the output go to the positive power supply.

What you need to add in your circuit is a pull up resistor. It is a resistor between the collector output and the power supply that will bring the voltage at the collector output up to the supply. Also you will need to connect the emitter out pin to GND to provide a current path to GND through the internal transistor.

Answer (score 3):

The [LM311](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm311.pdf?ts=1607873679024&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) is a bit of a strange one:

[image]

If you ground EMIT OUT or connect it to Vee (aka Vcc-) and take the output with a pullup resistor from COL OUT, you get the marked polarity on the inputs (the comparator output is inverted, and then the 'transistor' inverts it again).

If you connect COL OUT to Vcc and take the output from EMIT OUT with a pull-down resistor, the output 'transistor' is an emitter-follower so the output is inverted from what you'd expect from the input markings.

In some cases, such as the below schematic, you can draw outputs from both sides simultaneously:

[image]